# Hold Shift when right clicking?

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a way to automatically send <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right Click anytime a Right Click would normally be sent.

My current code works for single clicks however does not work when the mouse is held down.

```
RButton::
    Send, {Shift down}
    MouseClick, right
    Send, {Shift up}
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on the AHK forum by dmg:

```
RButton::
{
    Sendinput, {Shift down}{RButton down}
    keywait, RButton
    Sendinput, {RButton up}{Shift up}
}
Return
```